# Media query for mobile doesn't wok

Tags: css, mobile, media-queries

Hei
I have an mvc page that have some css for ipad and for mobile.

The query for ipad(@media only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) ) works fine, but i can't get the query for mobile to work.
I've tried this:

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px)
```

and this:

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 767px)
```

and this:

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width : 767px)
```

My meta looks like that:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
```

Tested on HTC ONE and iphone 4.

Comment: Don't include 'max device' make it so your queries look like this 

@media (max-width: 767px)

EDIT: or min-device for that matter

Comment: Try with `@media only screen and (max-width: 767px)`  without the max-device-width once

Comment: max-width didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've ended up putting the mobile section into separate file and having the query in link tag, this worked.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (min-device-width: 768px)" href="Content/Site.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (max-device-width: 767px)" href="Content/mobile.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px)
```

I know that `max-device-width` is used to target mobile devices such as iphone and android. But sometimes it's not recognized properly. So better use `max-width` without the device in it.